# vue-tables-2 color cell background

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I am trying to work out how to render a cell  with a specific background color based in text in the cell (eg ' green').

It seems that this may be possible using templates (https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#templates), but I don't follow how to use props.index within a single page vue app to render a specific cell a specific color.

```
<v-client-table :data="entries" :columns="['id', 'name' ,'age', 'edit']">
      <a slot="edit" slot-scope="props" class="fa fa-edit" :href="edit(props.row.id)"></a>
</v-client-table>
#Note: You can get the index of the current row relative to the entire data set using props.index
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is only a single cell and not the entire row you want colored correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct (been a while since I logged in)

Answer (score 3):

For those who need to apply some class to the entire row :

```
options: {
  rowClassCallback: function(row) { return 'bg-warning'}, //Using Boostrap4
}
```

**EDIT:**
I think [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#cells-conditional-styling) was updted.

```
cellClasses:{
  balance: [
    {
        class:'low-balance',
        condition: row => row.balance < 100
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do this for an single cell?

Comment: @proximacentauri you can use slots for that

`<div slot="columnName" slot-scope="props" :class="{'your-class': functionToCheckValue(props.row)}">{{props.row.columnName}}</div>`

[vue-tables-2 slots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#scoped-slots)